# Common fallacy of everything being its worst form

Tags: fallacies

What is the fallacy of equating everything with its worst example?

Slippery slope argument I guess, but I"m looking for something more specific.

Comment: could be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman

but i'm thinking of something that is more emotive ?

Comment: This is the worst question ever.

Comment: @DA I've seen way worse. This isn't a bad question. OP is asking for the name of this particular logical fallacy. "Love it or leave it." That means, "If you're going to criticize the government, then why not just leave the country?" There must be a name for that fallacy. This is a perfectly sensible question.

Comment: @user4894 I was making an attempt at being funny. I may have failed.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @MATHEMATICIAN, Can you rephrase your post in the format of a question. Are you asking, for example, "What is the fallacy of equating everything with its worst example?"

Comment: The phrasing is better, and it looks like you got some useful answers, but for posterity's sake, this question can still be improved. Can you give one or two examples of where you've seen this?

Comment: I'm not sure this is even a fallacy. Are you talking about taking things to their logical conclusion? The "slippery slope" fallacy requires jumping to conclusions not warranted by the premises. An example would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a reference claiming that "Love it or leave it" is the fallacy of *False Dilemma*.

> Definition: A limited number of options (usually two) is given, while
>   in reality there are more options. A false dilemma is an illegitimate
>   use of the "or" operator.
>
> Examples:
>
> (i) Either you're for me or against me.
>
> (ii) America: love it or leave it.

http://people.uncw.edu/kozloffm/logicalfallacies.html

Here is a second source labelling "Love it or leave it" as a False Dilemma.

https://eee.uci.edu/faculty/losh/resources/in-class/noblelf.html

Comment: i think false dilemma is sufficient. thank s !

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like they all have false premises. If I'm not mistaken your first example is :

> All communists are in North Korea.
>   You are a communist.
>   you should move to North Korea.

I'd say that most people believing the worst possible truths have valid logic but false premises.

Not all communists live in North Korea.

Comment: it's meant quite rhetorically.
1. all communists are like those in n korea
2. u are a communist
3. so you are like the communists of n korea... something like that anyway, they are just saying that every communist wants to create a n korean dystopia

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the right answer here, given that this is philosophy. This might be better as an english.se answer.

But I'd suggest 'hyperbolic' is perhaps what you are looking for. That's not really a philosophy, though.